# Conflict between empheq and tocdepth?

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, empheq

I have reduced my problem to a MWE and I have no idea what is going on.

The following code compiles and functions as expected when I remove the empheq package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{empheq} %Put boxes around multiline equations/equation environments

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{blahsec1}
\subsection{blah1}
\subsection{blah2}
\section{blahsec2}
 \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}} %
\subsection{blah1}
\subsection{blah2}

\end{document}
```

However, when I add the empheq package, I get the following error:

> Missing number, treated as zero.
>
> \begingroup  l.5 ...oup \aftergroup \calc@B \calc@A \begingroup
>                                                      \aftergroup \calc@B \calc... A number should have been here; I inserted `0'. (If you can't
>   figure out why I needed to see a number, look up`weird error' in the
>   index to The TeXbook.)
>
> ! Missing number, treated as zero.  
>                      \afterassignment  l.5 ...aftergroup \calc@B \calc@A \afterassignment
>                                                      \def {\GenericError {(cal... A number should have been here; I inserted `0'. (If you can't
>   figure out why I needed to see a number, look up`weird error' in the
>   index to The TeXbook.)

Comment: Add `\protect` before the `\setcounter` command.

Comment: ohh thanks!  do you want to make that an answer? i'll accept it

Comment: We can close as a duplicate of this question: [addtocontents not working with certain other packages](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/370518) (`empheq` loads `mathtools`).